# How to add 7 business days from current day in Salesforce Marketing Cloud through Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sfmc-business-unit

The scenario is to add 7 business days from today (exclude Saturday and Sunday).
Example:
If Today is monday, add 7 business days and my result should be next week Wednesday.
If today is Thursday, add 7 business days and my result should be next to next week Monday.

How can we handle this scenario using DateAdd function or any other function in Marketing cloud SQL query activity. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add 7 business days from a day so it will always be **+7** days.

The remaining thing to do is calculate the excluded days (weekend days) to add up.

If you spend some time calculating, you will realize:

- Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Sunday will have **2** excluded days.
- Thursday and Friday will have **4** excluded days.
- While Saturday will have **3** excluded days.

To determine the day of the week, the `DATEPART` function with argument `Weekday` would be helpful where it will return an integer corresponding with the day.

| Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 1 |

Combine all of them, here is what I write for the SQL

```SQL
SELECT
BookDate,
DATEADD(DAY, 7 + (CASE DATEPART(Weekday, BookDate)
  WHEN 1 THEN 2
  WHEN 2 THEN 2
  WHEN 3 THEN 2
  WHEN 4 THEN 2
  WHEN 7 THEN 3
  ELSE 4 END)
  , BookDate) AS BusinessDay
FROM DE1
```

Where BookDate is the date column you want to convert to the business day.

Try yourself here https://dbfiddle.uk/ayVHCvcG

I put the sample data with the days are Monday, Thursday, Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps